# Fwd: Issues porting application from tomcat 5.0.28 to tomcat 7.0.57

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

Can anyone please help me with the below. I even posted this in struts users group but no reply.

I am facing this issue after porting my application from the existing Tomcat 5.0.28 to the new tomcat 7.0.57. 
I am using Struts version 1.1 is something particular, the app in both the old and new environments work except for a few pages in the new env where when I click on the submit button it is directing to 
http://calculators/CertSsCalculator.do if I see the source of the page I see.

new environment (bombs due to //)

old environment (works fine)

The jsp is the same with no changes

Has any one see something like this and can suggest what can be tried and totally at a loss.

```
Here are the jsp files
```

edit.jsp

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>

<%@ page import="com.javabeans.DB" %>
<%@ page import="com.javabeans.SQLGenerator" %>
<%@ page import="com.struts.utils.DateField" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="CalculatorForm" class="com..struts.calculators.CalculatorForm" scope="request" >

<%
//--check login
String displayName = (String) session.getAttribute("displayName");
if(displayName == null) { response.sendRedirect( "/" );  return; }
//--get request para or session variables
String calc_id  =  (String)session.getAttribute("calc_id");
String advisorId = (String) session.getAttribute("userPID");
String clientId = (String) session.getAttribute("cclient_id");
//----set fields by database values, reset bean form
CertSsCalculatorForm.setFormId( calc_id );
CertSsCalculatorForm.setClientId( clientId );
CertSsCalculatorForm.setAdvisorId( advisorId );
CertSsCalculatorForm.reset();
%>

</jsp:useBean>


<jsp:forward page="call.jsp?"></jsp:forward>




</body>
</html>
```

here is the cal.jsp

```js
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld" prefix="nested" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs-datetime.tld" prefix="dt" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib  uri="/WEB-INF/pb.tld" prefix="pb" %>

<%

response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward compatibility
//--check login
String displayName = (String) session.getAttribute("displayName");
if(displayName == null) { response.sendRedirect( "/" );  return; }
//--get request para or session variables
String cclient_name = (String) session.getAttribute("cclient_name");

%>

<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link REL="shortcut icon" HREF="/images/pb.ico" TYPE="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/stylesheets/pb.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/stylesheets/cal.css" />
<script src="sscal_cert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body onload="javascript:checkSelection();adjPiaCommenceDate( this.form );adjSSLawYear(this.form);" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#330066" vlink="#006600" alink="#660066">
<div align="center">
<jsp:include page="/includes/nav.jsp" flush="true"/>


<!-- TABLE for body  -->
<table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>

<!-- COLUMN 1 for index  -->
      <td width="150" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <div align="center">
          <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
          <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      </div>
      </td>

<!-- COLUMN 2 for spacer  -->
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="1"><img src="/images/grey_spacer.gif" width="1" height="100%"></td>

<!-- COLUMN 3 -->
<td valign="top" align="center" width="629" background="/images/icon_background.gif">
<!-- ============================================================ -->


<!-- DIV for title -->
<div id="title" style="font:100% arial; color:#330066;" >
Social Security Calculator for
<br>
<%=cclient_name %>
</div>
<!-- DIV for nav -->
<div id="nav" style="margin-left:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8; font:80% arial; text-align:left; color:#330066;" >
<a href="../client/home.jsp">Back</a>
</div>






<div>
<html:errors/>
<html:form action="/calculators/Calculator" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
<html:hidden property="minStartAge" value="10"/>
<html:hidden property="numOfAges" value="90"/>
<table class="content" width="100%">

    <tr style="display:none">
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Client Name </th>
    <td><html:text property="clientName" styleClass="general-input-text"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Name </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="calcName" styleClass="general-input-text"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display:none">
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Form ID </th>
    <td><html:text property="formId" styleClass="general-input-text"/></td>
    </tr>


  <!--  -->

  <tr>
    <td class="group_title" colspan="3">
     Beneficiary Information
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr style="display:none">
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2" width="200px"> <bean:message key="general.name"/></th>
    <td >
      <html:text property="name" styleClass="general-input-text"/>
    </td>
  </tr>


<!-- INS:dob  -->
  <tiles:insert page="../datefield_read.jsp">
    <tiles:put name="property" value="dob"/>
    <tiles:put name="bean" beanName="CalculatorForm"/>
    <tiles:put name="titleKey" value="dob.title" />
  </tiles:insert>
  <tiles:insert page="../datefield.jsp">
    <tiles:put name="property" value="dob"/>
    <tiles:put name="bean" beanName="CalculatorForm"/>
    <tiles:put name="titleKey" value="dob.title" />
  </tiles:insert>
<!-- ENDINS:dob  -->



  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2">Calculation Type</th>
    <td>
      <html:radio property="retType"
    value="oldAge"
    onchange="switchDodInput( this.form )" />
      Old-Age Retirement<br/>
      <html:radio property="retType"
    value="disability"
    onchange="switchDodInput( this.form )" />Disability Retirement
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tiles:insert page="/calculators/datefield.jsp">
    <tiles:put name="property" value="dod"/>
    <tiles:put name="bean" beanName="CalculatorForm"/>
    <tiles:put name="titleKey" value="disability.date.title" />
    <tiles:put name="yearChangeJs" value="adjDisabilityDate( this.form )" />
  </tiles:insert>
  <tiles:insert page="/calculators/datefield.jsp">
    <tiles:put name="property" value="doc"/>
    <tiles:put name="bean" beanName="CalculatorForm"/>
    <tiles:put name="titleKey" value="pia.date.title" />
    <tiles:put name="yearChangeJs" value="adjEarningStopYear( this.form )" />
  </tiles:insert>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="group_sep"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="group_title" colspan="3">
     Social Security Benefit Options
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> <bean:message key="sscal.law.year"/> </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="ssLawYear" styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> <bean:message key="sscal.earning.stop.year"/> </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="earningStopYear" styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> <bean:message key="sscal.earning.fwd.rate"/> </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="earningFwdRate" styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>%
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Backward Earnings Projection</th>
    <td>
      <html:select property="earningBwdProjection" onchange="switchBwdFixedRateInput( this.form )">
 <html:option value="us_avg">US Average Wage</html:option>
 <html:option value="fixed">Fixed Rate Projection</html:option>
 <html:option value="zero">Zero Earnings</html:option>
      </html:select>
      <span id="bwdFixedRateInput" style="visibility:hidden" >
 <html:text property="earningBwdFixedRate"
     styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>%
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> <bean:message key="sscal.cola.rate"/> </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="colaIncRate" styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>%
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> <bean:message key="sscal.wb.rate"/> </th>
    <td>
      <html:text property="wageIncRate" styleClass="year-input-text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>%
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2 "> Earning always exceed wage base </th>
    <td>
      <html:checkbox property="earningExceedWagebase"
       onchange="switchKnownYearsInput( this.form )"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="knownYearsInput" style="visibility:visible">
    <th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Known Earnings Years </th>
    <td>
      from <html:text property="knownEarningStartYear"
        styleClass="year-input-text"
        size="4"
        maxlength="4"/>
      to <html:text property="knownEarningStopYear"
      styleClass="year-input-text"
      size="4"
      maxlength="4"/>
      <html:submit property="subOperation" styleClass="btn">
 <c:choose>
   <c:when test='${CalculatorForm.inputEarning}'>
     <bean:message key="sscal.op.changeEarnings"/>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
     <bean:message key="sscal.op.enterEarnings"/>
   </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
      </html:submit>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="group_sep"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<c:if test='${CalculatorForm.inputEarning}'>
  <table class="content" width="100%" id="knownEarnings">
    <tr>
      <td class="group_title" colspan="3">
Earnings History
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th></th><td></td>

      <td>
 <html:button property="" styleClass="btn" onclick="resetEarnings( this.form )">
Reset all earnings
 </html:button>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <logic:iterate name="CalculatorForm"
     property="knownEarnings"
     id="knownEarningItem"
     indexId="index">
      <tr>
 <th align="right" width="190px">
   <html:hidden name="knownEarningItem" property="year" indexed="true"/>
   <c:out value="${knownEarningItem.year}"/>
 </th>
 <td width="10px"></td>
 <td>
   <html:text styleClass="general-input-text"
       name="knownEarningItem" property="value" indexed="true"/>
 </td>
      </tr>
    </logic:iterate>


    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="group_sep"></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</c:if>


<!-- signature -->
<table class="content" >
<tr><td colspan="3" class="group_sep"></td></tr>
<tr>
<th class="field_name_indent" colspan="2"> Signed by </th>
<td>
    <html:select property="advisorName">
  <html:option value=""></html:option>
  <html:option value="First Last">First Last</html:option>
  <html:option value="First Last">First Last</html:option>
    </html:select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="content" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">

      <html:image property="" border="0" src="/images/submit.gif"/>

    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</html:form>
</div>


<!-- ============================================================ -->

</td>
<!-- END OF COLUMN 3 -->


</tr>
</table>
<!-- END OF TABLE for body  -->


<jsp:include page="/includes/footer.jsp" flush="true"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for validateform:

```js
function validateForm() {

    form = document.forms["CalculatorForm"];
    if ( ! validPiaCommenceDate( form ) ) {
               return false;
    } 
    return true;
  
}

function validPiaCommenceDate( form ) {

    dobYearInput = form.elements["dob.year"][0];
    dobMonthInput = form.elements["dob.monthOfYear"][0];
    dobDayInput = form.elements["dob.dayOfMonth"][0];
    
    docYearInput = form.elements["doc.year"];
    docMonthInput = form.elements["doc.monthOfYear"];
    docDayInput = form.elements["doc.dayOfMonth"];

    var valid = true;
    var dob = new Date( dobYearInput.value, dobMonthInput.value-1, dobDayInput.value );    
    var doc = new Date( docYearInput.value, docMonthInput.value-1, docDayInput.value );    
    var pia = calcPiaCommenceDate( parseInt(dobYearInput.value), parseInt(dobMonth.value), parseInt(dobDayInput.value) );

    if ( earlierThan(doc, pia) ) {
               valid = false;
               alert( "PIA Commence Date cannot be earlier than: " + (parseInt(pia.getMonth())+1) + "/" + pia.getDate() + "/" + pia.getFullYear() );
    } else {
               valid = true;
    }

    return valid;                   
}

function earlierThan( date1, date2 ) {
               var valid = false;

               y1 = date1.getFullYear();
               m1 = date1.getMonth();
               d1 = date1.getDate();

               y2 = date2.getFullYear();
               m2 = date2.getMonth();
               d2 = date2.getDate();
               
    dif_year = y2 - y1 ; 
    dif_month = m2 - m1 ; 
    dif_day = d2 - d1 ; 
    if ( dif_year>0 ) {
               valid = true;
    }
    if ( dif_year==0 && dif_month>0 ) {
               valid = true;
    }
    if ( dif_year==0 && dif_month==0 && dif_day>0 ) {
               valid = true;
    }
   
    return valid;
}

function calcPiaCommenceDate(year, month, day)
{
               var pia_year       = year + 62;
               var pia_month   = month;
               var pia_day        = day - 1 ;
               if ( month==1 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_year = year + 61;
                              pia_month = 12;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==2 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==3 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 28;
               }
               if ( month==4 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==5 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 30;
               }
               if ( month==6 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==7 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 30;
               }
               if ( month==8 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==9 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==10 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 30;
               }
               if ( month==11 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 31;
               }
               if ( month==11 && day==1 ) {
                              pia_month = month-1;
                              pia_day = 30;
               }
               
    var d = new Date();
               d.setFullYear( pia_year, pia_month-1, pia_day );    
               return d;
}
```

Comment: How this could happen?

Comment: I don't know. that is what confusing me. below is more detail
 
 The flow is edit.jsp, this has a <jsp:forward page="call.jsp?"></jsp:forward>, the call.jsp has <html:form action="/calculators/Calculator" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >,  but in the view source I see it as <form name="CalculatorForm" method="post" action="//calculators/Calculator.do"> and this doesnt work as there is a "//" instead of "/".
 
 Any suggestions what could be causing this? If it is because of the jsp:forward tag then how was it working before the upgrade?

Comment: This is something weird that you didn't post the source code to the question.

Comment: Hi Roman, I have added the 2 jsp files. Please let me know if you have find anything. Thanks

Comment: What is the code for `validateForm()`?

Comment: Updated the code for validateForm(). Please let me know if you need anymore. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: I don't see anything that modifies the form action attribute.

Comment: You have a lot of javascript called on load, check that stuff.

Comment: The same code works on the other machine which has Tomcat 5.x but when copied to tomcat 7.x just this functionality broke and the rest is working fine. There is no code change but we will check on that.

Comment: I never seen such behavior, do you know that your question is off-topic, because to get hep on SO you should post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems someone already ran into this  http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/struts-html-form-resolving-action-with-double-slashes.504971/

In particular refer to the comment

My incorrect  read:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="D:/Website/" ... >
```

and the correct one:

```
<Context path="" docBase="D:/Website/" ... >
```